# Excel con Libreria Spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, xls

Estoy trabajando con la Libreria Spreadsheet para crear archivos en Excel con PHP. Mi problema es,  que necesito que al presionar el icono de Excel en mi pagina WEB, el archivo no se descargue sino que se abra en una nueva pestaña en el navegador, hasta ahora he buscado pero no encuentro nada
Espero que alguien me pueda orientar por favor.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup;

 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('CALAMA');

  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SOLICITUD 
 CALAMA.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
   $writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que pretendes harían falta dos cosas:

### 1. Usar el encabezado correcto en el código

En primer lugar, no estarías usando el encabezado correcto para que tu contenido se muestre en el navegador.

En el protocolo HTTP el encabezado `Content-Disposition` sirve para indicar si el archivo debe ser descargado, o mostrado en el navegador, como bien dice [la documentación](https://docs.w3cub.com/http/headers/content-disposition):

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either `inline` (default
> value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the
> Web page) or `attachment` (indicating it should be downloaded; most
> browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of
> the filename parameters if present).

---

> El primer parámetro en el contexto HTTP es `inline` -en línea- (valor
> predeterminado, que indica que se puede mostrar dentro de la página
> web, o como la página web) o `attachment` -adjunto- (que indica que
> debe descargarse; la mayoría de los navegadores presentan un cuadro de
> diálogo 'Guardar como', precargado con el valor de los parámetros de
> `filename` -nombre de archivo- si están presentes).

Por tanto, con respecto a las cabeceras, para que un archivo se abra en el navegador tienes que usar:

```
Content-Disposition: inline
```

Es decir, cambiar esto:

```
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SOLICITUD CALAMA.xlsx"');
```

Por esto:

```
  header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="SOLICITUD CALAMA.xlsx"');
```

Para más detalles puedes ver también [la documentación en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

### 2. Que el navegador pueda abrir archivos Excel

Como bien señala @Marcos en su comentario e @Ivandez en su respuesta, si tu navegador no tiene instalada una extensión que permita abrir desde el mismo  archivos Excel, esto no va a funcionar. Si es tu caso, [consulta el siguiente post](https://www.alphr.com/open-excel-sheets-without-excel/), donde son explicados varios métodos para poder visualizar Excel desde el navegador.

Aquí tienes también un enlace a la [extensión de Office en Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj) (cortesía también de @Marcos).

Comment: Esto funciona si y solo si tenes instalada una extensión que permita al navegador procesar archivos de la extensión en cuestión.

Comment: Cierto @Marcos, me permito agregar tu comentario al final de la respuesta. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Ya que estamos, te dejo [este post](https://www.alphr.com/open-excel-sheets-without-excel/) por si quisieras agregar mas info al respecto.

Comment: Puntualmente para archivos de `MS Office` [esta es la extensión](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió, hice el cambio en el código e instale la extensión y logre hacerlo, pero tengo una consulta mas, es posible que el excel se visualice en una pestaña nueva ?? lo que hizo fue abrir el excel en la misma pestaña de mi pagina.

Comment: @JeisonDavilaLlanten supongo que si le pones [`target="_blank"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H83.html) al enlace que te genera el archivo, se abrirá en una nueva pestaña del navegador.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede hacer lo que necesitas porqué el navegador no es capaz de interpretar una hoja de calculo y por ende no puede abrir un excel en otra pestaña.

El autor quiere abrir un excel en una nueva pestaña así como el navegador abre una imagen o un audio, no se puede ya que el navegador no es capaz de interpretar un excel.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/301624)

Comment: @CandidMoe el autor quiere abrir un excel en una nueva pestaña así como el navegador abre una imagen o un audio y yo respondí que no se puede ya que el navegador no es capaz de interpretar un excel, no es un critica ni aclaración, es una repuesta.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo, pero el OP ya probó y aceptó otra respuesta. Por eso es mejor dejar un comentario y dejar que el tiempo y la falta de respuestas te den la razón.